# How to reference a maven property within another property?

Tags: maven, properties, reference, pom.xml

Assume I get a properties file from somewhere, that has this define:

```
dog=POODLE
```

And when running maven, I pass a parameter with the property name to look up:

```
mvn clean install -animal=dog
```

I need to be able to retrieve in the pom.xml the value `"POODLE"` without knowing what's the property to look up for (I don't know yet that I'm looking up for a "dog", but only that I'm looking up for an "animal").

Can this be done?

I can reference in the pom `${animal}` which will be replaced with `dog`, but then I need to look that up.

I was innocent enough to try the following, but it won't work:

```
${${animal}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It should work if you use `-Danimal=${dog}`. Here is my example

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>nested-property</groupId>
    <artifactId>nested-property</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <dog>POODLE</dog>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-echo-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>echo</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <echos>
                        <echo>Animal: ${animal}</echo>
                    </echos>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

run with: `mvn -Danimal=${dog} install`

results in

```
[INFO] --- maven-echo-plugin:0.1:echo (default) @ nested-property ---
[INFO] Animal: POODLE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is a working solution (thanks!), but let's change this a little:

Let's say, you still receive a parameter `-Danimal=dog`.
And inside the `pom.xml` I now need to retrieve two different property values: `dog.name=TONY` and `dog.race=POODLE`.
    
Where I know for sure that, no matter what animal I get through a parameter, I will always want to reference these properties by suffixing `${animal}.name` and `${animal}.race`.

Any thought of how can I just pass the `"dog"` value once and reuse it, instead of having to pass two different parameters: `-Danimal.name=TONY -Danimal.race=PODDLE`?

Comment: @Tomer K Maybe you should consider to use different [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for different property constellations.

Comment: Remember that on nearly all shells on UNIX / Linux / OS X, you'll have to quote that command line parameter, otherwise your shell will substitute before Maven and `animal` will be unset. So, use `mvn -Danimal=\${dog} install`