# Maven : Use a property value in a property name ... ie ${env.${some.prop}}

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

Is it possible, when referring to a property, to use another property's value in order to specify a property name ?

Example :
OS environment variables :
- WAS-USR-V1_HOME = a_path
- WAS-USR-V2_HOME = another_path

In my build, i want to use one of the two, letting the user choose between V1 or V2 by passing a property named "suffix" (`-Dsuffix=V1` for example).

How can i do it in the POM ?
I'd like to set a property like :
`<my.prop>${env.WAS-${env.USERNAME}-${suffix}_HOME}</my.prop>`
Which must be intermediately evaluated to : `${env.WAS-USR-V1_HOME}` ...
Finally `${my.prop}` will be evaluated to `a_path`

Thank's !

Steve

Precisions :
- The user does NOT know the env variable name. He only knows the "suffix".
- Another part of the variable name is the "Username" set by OS
- The "my.prop" property needs to be generic (the same whatever username or suffix)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference a maven property within another property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074634/how-to-reference-a-maven-property-within-another-property)

Comment: Seems to be the same problem. However, answer doesn't match. The user only knows a "part" of the variable name ... He does NOT know the variable name, he can only say "V1" ...

Comment: The logic looks very complex, maybe there is some flaw. Can you explain the big picture? What do you want to achieve? And did you think of directly building the path? like: `<my.prop>${base_path}/${env.USERNAME}/home/${suffix}/foo/</my.prop>`

Comment: The path is set by another component, and from a user to another is not based on the same pattern. Only the env variables are build on the same pattern : WAS-<USERNAME>-<SUFFIX>_HOME where the suffix is choosen by the user. The env variables WAS-<USERNAME>-<SUFFIX>_HOME contains the path of an application server profile. A user can have x profile, and need to indicate the suffix when launching the build.

Comment: I precise actually the user doesn't know the existence of these env variables ... He only knows the suffix because he give that to some component responsible for profile creation ... The solution can be to teach the users how the env variables are made. But before i'd like to be sure that building dynamically the profile variable name is not possible

Comment: Why can't you tell the "another component" what the user and suffix is? So instead of building a lot of vars, only build one with the correct path (It is very hard to help you because what you want is not possible, and we don't know what the complete project is, so we can't provide a better solution)

Comment: I have 50 users, the other components can't be easily modified ... and profile path are OS type, OS version, user profile and projects version dependent. The only normalized information is the name of the env variable containing the profile path

Comment: Another question that arises is, why is your build user dependent? How do you build on for example a build server? Or the production build? Why can't the user give you the complete path to the users profile?

Comment: It's a developer build, once compiled and packaged, the application is deployed on a local was profile. Every user can have multiple WAS profiles, and that's why the build is user profile dependent. The servers and production build are made by the CI (actually Bamboo)

Comment: Then i would suggest that the user tells you the absolute path to its WAS profile, `mvn -Dpath.profile=/home/usr/was/v2/`

Comment: I know this ... This is precisely what i do when a user ask me to make their build without errors. But it's not a solution to my problem. The users don't know where there profiles are ... they only know the suffix they gave to their WAS profile ... they are around 50, there are different places, and i spend my life going here or there for "fixing" these problems. The concept is industrialization and making the different script working without modifications, and minimalist technical data knowledge.

Comment: Ok. Last try: call a script from maven (this can even be: mvn -f otherComponent/pom.xml) with the suffix, and use the return value (the correct path for this user and suffix) in a property. Furthermore, this is in my opinion not really build related. Write a script file (e.g. `./gimmePathForWASProfileSuffix.sh V2`) which returns the correct path and the user calls `mvn -Dwas.path` with this path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would require recursive resolution of properties and afaik it does NOT work.